# Is the predictive "historical analysis" on the 2021 Taliban strategy (provided to the US Congress) a public document?

Tags: united-states, congress, afghanistan, taliban, intelligence

An [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/08/17/us/politics/afghanistan-biden-administration.html) in The New York Times from August 18 says:

> A historical analysis provided to Congress concluded that the Taliban had learned lessons from their takeover of the country in the 1990s. This time, the report said, the militant group would first secure border crossings, commandeer provincial capitals and seize swaths of the country’s north before moving in on Kabul, a prediction that proved accurate.

Is this "historical analysis" document public, or was it provided in a closed session to some committee?